# Codeigniter 'Message: Undefined index: site_lang' issue at first load

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session, multilingual

I have developed a website and it is working fine in my localhost.
But I wanted to test it in a local area network before going live.
There is an issue I am facing which is at first load in a browser or any other machine it shows below error until I change the language once. When I change the language once then the issue is never happening again.
I am new and this is my first project so can anyone help me in this regard.
Thanks in advance

A PHP Error was encountered

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: site_lang

Filename: models/companies.php

Line Number: 15
```

Backtrace:

```
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\fp\application\models\companies.php
Line: 15
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\fp\application\controllers\home.php
Line: 19
Function: get_companies

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\fp\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Here is my Model:

```
 //---- Table Companies ---
public function get_companies()
{   
    // Retrieve titles for all languages 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `ci_companies` WHERE `co_id` = 1"; 
    // Retrieve appropriate title according to the chosen language in the system 
    $sql = "SELECT `co_id`, `co_name`, SUBSTRING(`co_detail`,1,100) AS `co_detail`, `co_img`, `co_img2` FROM `ci_companies` WHERE `co_lang` = '".$_SESSION['site_lang']."'";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result();
}
```

And here is my controller:

```
function switchLang($language = "") {

    $language = ($language != "") ? $language : "english";
    $this->session->set_userdata('site_lang', $language);

    redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

}
```

Comment: Re edit your question with the companies model and home controller so we can see some code

Comment: Please check it now. Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this.error due to wrong use of `single quotes`.

```
$language = $this->session->userdata('site_lang');//or $_SESSION['site_lang']

$sql = "SELECT `co_id`, `co_name`, SUBSTRING(`co_detail`,1,100) AS `co_detail`, `co_img`, `co_img2` FROM `ci_companies` WHERE `co_lang` = '{$language}'";
```

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense since the variable name is ok.
Also I can share the error line code where I call session language..

    public function get_companies()
    {   
        // Retrieve titles for all languages 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `ci_companies` WHERE `co_id` = 1"; 

        $sql = "SELECT `co_id`, `co_name`, SUBSTRING(`co_detail`,1,100) AS `co_detail`, `co_img`, `co_img2` FROM `ci_companies` WHERE `co_lang` = '".$_SESSION['site_lang']."'";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $query->result();  
    }

Comment: Also post your code in question.I have answered according to error.

Comment: Thank you  @Hek mat .
I got the issue and your solution.

Comment: No again there was another problem. No records came to my page later when I refresh the page. Because there is no data in session I think so it makes my condition wrong that's why there is no data.
In my own condition it returns data unless once I change the language.
It is strange issue.

Comment: print your session data `print_r($_SESSION)`

Comment: Now I can explain my issue better. When I load the page at first time or in another word session ends, it returns null but after I change language once it returns the preferred language and it happens when I publish it in LAN but in localhost all is well.

Comment: Check session for language first.If session value is not set then set the default language otherwise use session language value.

Comment: like this `$lang = $this->session->has_userdata('langauge')?$this->session->userdata('language'):'english';`.

Comment: Actually I had a separate controller for language switcher.
Now I set the same session isset control to my main controller and problem solved. I will punch my face with this stupid problem.
But your ideas helped me a lot thank you so much @Hek mat
----------------
function switchLang($language = "") {
        $language = ($language != "") ? $language : "english";
        $this->session->set_userdata('site_lang', $language);
    }

Comment: yes problem is due session when session expires or initially not set.Glad to help you.Happy coding.Feel free to accept answer and upvote so others may get help.